# Mobile security solutions

Tags: iphone, android, security, mobile

What are the mobile handset security solutions used by you / your organization.

What are the pro's and cons of usage of these solution - and how far have you been successful in implementing these - were there any loopholes / issues faced in using them?.

In general, can you suggest a set of guidelines to watch for when going for going for selecting a specific solution in this context.

Are these solutions also inter-operable/compatible with the solutions used on the PC's/laptops.

Comment: i think serverfault guys can give better answers.

Comment: Thanks, I have posted it there, solutions can be both at hardware and software layers - so keeping it open here.

Comment: Define mobile.  Any form of client-side scripting is generally referred to as mobile code in the realm of software and security analysis.

Answer (score 0):

We like using the android platform for a few reasons.

1) Tracking "company resources".  If you are going to see hookers and you have a company phone,  then we know about it.  We if you are kidnapped, then we know your last location.

2) [Remote wipe](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2-highlights.html)  If a phone is stolen,  it could have company passwords or other intellectual property on them.  This is important to our information retention policy.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to following links

https://www.owasp.org/images/4/40/OWASP_Advanced_Mobile_Application_Code_Review_Techniques.pptx

Register here for more
lab.nowsecure.com

https://www.owasp.org/images/9/94/MobileTopTen.pdf

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.